# Can't use Android library after migration from JCenter to MavenCentral. Error: Could not find :unspecified:

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I've just migrated my Android lib from JCenter to MavenCentral. The process completed successfully and I can find my lib through [Sonatype Repo Search](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.techyourchance/threadposter).

However, when I try to use the lib in my sample application, I get the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':sample:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':sample:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find :unspecified:.
     Required by:
         project :sample > com.techyourchance:threadposter:1.0.0

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

It looks like Gradle finds my lib (because if I change to a non-existent version, say 2.0.0, then I get completely different error), but there is some problem with the artifact.

All the source code (both the lib and the sample app) can be found [here](https://github.com/techyourchance/thread-poster). Specifically, here is [build.gradle](https://github.com/techyourchance/thread-poster/blob/master/threadposter/build.gradle) of the lib and [that's the additional Gradle script](https://github.com/techyourchance/thread-poster/blob/master/threadposter/publish-maven.gradle) that handles publication to Sonatype.

I've already spent two hours searching for each of the above error messages on the internet, but couldn't solve this issue so far.

Comment: I had this problem. Could you try remove `jitpack` if you have? Or could you try repositories in this order: https://github.com/Drjacky/ImagePicker/issues/10#issuecomment-808258636

Comment: I don't see why Jitpack would break MavenCentral?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce  Me neither. I had the issue and did that and it worked but, seems the accepted answer is the correct solution. I'm gonna do the same for mine as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Skip dependencies with name 'unspecified' in your publish-maven.gradle.

```
withXml {
    def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')

    project.configurations.implementation.allDependencies.each {
        if (it.name != 'unspecified') {
            def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
            dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
            dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
            dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was indeed the problem. However, as recommended by another developer, I ended up just removing this entire `withXml` block and it seem to work alright now. Nevertheless, your answer is also correct, so I'll accept it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: while this works, I suggest checking the group of dependency as safety guard for a broader check
````it.group != null````

Comment: @Artur Artikov @Vasiliy @Dr.jacky Thanks so much for this, I've been having a similar issue and this looks like a prime candidate for a solution.  I have a related question though: How did you test this without actually publishing it first?  I know you can include aar files as local dependencies, however doing that doesn't replicate the `Could not find :unspecified` error.  Any thoughts on how one would test this without actually publishing to Maven Central?